# Bounded wildcards for class and super class array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, superclass

I have a class `Shape` and a class `Circle` that extends `Shape` as follows:

```
public class Shape {
  private double area;
  public Shape(double thatArea) {
      this.area = thatArea;
  }

  public double getArea() {
      return this.area;
  }
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
    private double radius;
    public Circle(double radius) {
        super(3.14*radius*radius);
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return this.radius;
    }
}
```

Supposed that I create an array of shapes as follows

```
Shape[] shapes = new Shape[3];
shapes[0] = new Shape(100.0);
shapes[1] = new Circle(5.0);
shapes[2] = new Shape(35.0);
```

And have a filter by area method like this

```
public Shape[] filterByMaxArea(double maxArea) {
    ArrayList<Shape> shapeResult = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Shape s : shapes) {
        if (s.getArea < maxArea) shapeResult.add(s);
    }

    return (Shape[]) shapeResult.toArray();
}
```

If I call the `filterByMaxArea()` method like this

```
filterByMaxArea(1000); // in order to include the 
circle too
```

Then the compiler throws a `ClassCastException`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lmypackage.Shape;
at mypackage.Main.filterByMaxArea(Main.java:74)
```

Where line 74 in the code is this

```
return (Shape[]) shapeResult.toArray();
```

Can someone explain me why does the cast fail even though the Circle is a subtype of Shape and previously I had an array of Shape and Circle instances ?

P.S I have tried also declaring the ArrayList with bounded wildcards without any luck.

```
 ArrayList<? extends Shape> shapeResult = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toArray()` returns `Object[]`, there is a overloaded version of `toArray(T[] a)` which will give the desired result, use it like

```
return shapeResult.toArray(new Shape[shapeResult.size()]);
```

Comment: I was thinking about using it, is that the only way to cast it back ? Would you mind explaining how and why would it work ?

Comment: @LucianEnache java generic erasure causes issues in creating generic arrays, we have to ultimately use `Array.newInstance()`. i haven't looked at `toArray(T[] a)` implementation but i believe that's what it uses, here's more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: @Lucian Enache Generics appeared in Java 1.5 but before Java 1.5, the `Object[] toArray()` method was already defined in the Collection interface. So Java API developers kept them in Java 1.5 and later version to not break the API. In most of cases (as you use generic type) this overloaded method is not convenient. Use `T[]  toArray(T[] a)` rather

Answer (score 1):

`toArray()` is overloaded to return an array of the type of the generic declared in the collection :

```
T[] List.toArray(T[] a)
```

But in fact you don't need that.
You could use `Stream.toArray(IntFunction)` to create a array of `Shape` from the `List`.

With the actual code you could do :

```
return shapeResult.stream().toArray(Shape[]::new);
```

that is more elegant than :

```
return shapeResult.toArray(new Shape[shapeResult.size()]);
```

Or by using a full stream approach, the whole method could be written :

```
public Shape[] filterByMaxArea(double maxArea) {
     return Arrays.stream(shapes)
                  .filter(s -> s.getArea() < maxArea)
                  .toArray(Shape[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the point of your question:

Lets look at 2 examples with arrays:

**This works:**

```
Object[] array = new MyObject[2];
MyObject[] myarrau = (MyObject[])os; //ok, since array is of type MyObject[]
```

**This does not** (gives java.lang.ClassCastException like in your case)

```
Object[] array = new Object[2];
MyObject[] myarrau = (MyObject[])os; //ClassCastException  here since array is not type of MyObject[]
```

And snippet from `toArray` code of the `ArrayList` class:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    Object[] r = new Object[size()];
    return r;
}
```

As you see the returned array is of `Object[]` type like in above second example.